# Python Import system, importing function from a module that imports the same function from another package

Tags: python, import, python-module

Came across code with following structure:

```
/root
  /app
    __init__.py
    mod1.py
    mod2.py
  /lib
    __init__.py
    libmod.py
```

mod1:

```
from lib.libmod import somefunc
```

mod2:

```
from app.mod1 import somefunc
```

While there are no runtime errors with this, my gut tells me that mod2 should import somefunc from lib. I have limited understanding of the python import system, but I`m concered about importing imports/code running twice or doing some kind of polution of namespaces.Should I be concerned at all, or is this perfectly fine Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly fine. The `from x import name` statement merely imports `name` from `x` – it does not care where `name` was initially defined.

In fact, the standard library itself frequently re-exports names from internal or C modules.

```py
# collections/abc.py
from _collections_abc import *
from _collections_abc import __all__
from _collections_abc import _CallableGenericAlias
```

Re-exporting names can help make the public appearance of a package simpler to use, while giving complete freedom to how the implementation is structured.

However, one should be careful when re-exporting names *across* packages. Just because a package exposes a name today does not mean that a future version does so as well. When the intermediate package is not under your control, avoid making assumptions and prefer importing from the official source.

```py
# bad: import undocumented attribute
from subprocess import os
# good: import with official name
import os
```

---

The notion of "where" an object was defined does not generally make sense. For example, consider defining a module for literal constants:

```py
# constants.py
MIDNIGHT = 0
NOON = 12
```

There is a single value for every `0` and `12` *throughout the entire application*. The statement `from constants import MIDNIGHT, NOON` has no way of checking where the objects were defined initially.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have on occacion  importet stuff from modules in the __init__.py just to make stuff a bit more user-friendly, especially when functionality is a bit scattered around submodules. As I had no runtime issues, I kind of assumed it worked fine.